# The field $\mathbb{Q}(\cos \frac {2\pi} {n})$

Tags: number-fields, fields, nt.number-theory

Let $x$ be $\cos \displaystyle \frac {2\pi} {n}$ for some natural number $n$.
Then is there an integer $n$ such that $\mathbb{Q}(x^2+x)\neq \mathbb{Q}(x)$?
I also would like to know if there is some known algorithm or computer program to find such $n$.

Comment: Have you taken a course in Galois theory? This would be a good homework problem for such a course, and as such is not on topic here. 

Comment: If so, I would appreciate for any hint.

Comment: One field inclusion is trivial, so I would say: search what the other means...

Comment: Hint: If $\mathbb{Q}(x^2+x)$ is strictly smaller than $\mathbb{Q}(x)$, then there be some nontrivial element of $Gal(\mathbb{Q}(x)/\mathbb{Q})$ which fixes $x^2+x$. How could it happen that an automorphism fixes $x^2+x$ but not $x$? 